# Multiple sequential input dialogs?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm writing a program that involves multiple input dialogs for filling an array.

In the first input dialog, an integer N is entered by the user.

Subsequently N input dialogs should be displayed, asking the user for the data to put into the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not expect someone to do your homework for you. Hint: use [loop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Control_Loops).

Comment: What have you tried, show code (and variable definitions) and where it fails.

Comment: Are you having any trouble with your task? If so, please elaborate. If not, thanks for sharing your story.

Answer (score 1):

This simple function provides a means of entering an arbitrary-length array of strings:

```
type TDynStrArray = array of string;

function ArrayInput: TDynStrArray;
const
  SCaption = 'Array input';
  SLengthPrompt = 'Please enter the length of the array:';
  SElementPrompt = 'Please enter element %d in the array:';
var
  slen: string;
  len: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  slen := '1';
  if not InputQuery(SCaption, SLengthPrompt, slen) then Exit;
  if not (TryStrToInt(slen, len) and (len >= 0)) then
  begin
    ShowMessageFmt('Invalid natural number: "%s".', [slen]);
    Exit;
  end;
  SetLength(result, len);
  for i := 0 to len - 1 do
    if not InputQuery(SCaption, Format(SElementPrompt, [i+1]), result[i]) then
      Exit;
end;
```

To try it, add the above code to a new VCL project, and add a `TMemo` control to the main form. Then add an `OnCreate` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TDynStrArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  a := ArrayInput;
  Memo1.Clear;
  for i := 0 to Length(a) - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(a[i]);
end;
```